# emulate a function that propagate into every field like operator= and destructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, raii

As I understand, there are some special functions that propagate to every field members by default.    :-
copy assignment, copy constructor, move assignment, move constructor, destructor, etc.

```
class B{};
class C{B b;};     
C c1;  C c2;
c1=c2; //<-- automatic invoke B::operator=()
```

Is it possible to deploy some C++ trick to create/emulate a custom function that has such a cool feature?

If no, it is a complete answer.
If yes, please show demo ; I believe it should be a free function e.g. :-

```
class A{};
class B{};
void f(A a){}
class C{public: A a;B b;};     
//no need to code "void f(C c){f(c.a);}"
C c1;  
f(c1);  //<-- automatic invoke f(c1.a), but not invoke f(c1.b)
```

**Template function** and **SFINAE** might be useful but I don't know how to apply in this case.

I think it may be useful for some more advance RAII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `as_tie`:

```
struct C{
  A a;
  B b;
  friend auto as_tie(C& c){
    return std::tie(c.a, c.b);
  }
};
```

you need to write this for every type you want to interact with in this way; there is no way to avoid that until compile-time reflection arrives in C++.  However, `as_tie` makes things like `==`, `swap`, and the like easy to implement, so you get bonus payoff.

After that, a mixture of foreach-tuple-element, override set objects, y-combinators, and invoke-if-possible gives you the ability to say "recursively apply `f` to each of its members".

Barring you having to do this dozens of times in a variety of contexts, it won't be worth it.

In short, no, not really.  But maybe sorta with a lot of work.